# Update Set command works in Access but not in Visual Studio with @parameters

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have been working on a personal project for the company I work for to control stock levels in order to practice my c#.

I want my application to search through tblJuiceStock, find a matching FlavourID to what the user is inputting and update the stock of that record through an UPDATE SET query.

```
 public void InsertJuiceStockWithCheck()
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();

            string tblJuiceStockCheck = "SELECT FlavourID, Quantity FROM tblJuiceStock";
            OleDbCommand cmdCheck = new OleDbCommand(tblJuiceStockCheck, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter daCheck = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdCheck);
            DataTable dtCheck = new DataTable();
            daCheck.Fill(dtCheck);

            foreach (DataRow row in dtCheck.Rows)
            {
                if ((int)row["FlavourID"] == fID)
                {
                    int currentQty = (int)row["Quantity"];
                    int updatedQty = currentQty + qty;
                    string tblJuiceStockExisting = @"UPDATE tblJuiceStock
                                                    SET Quantity = @newquantity 
                                                    WHERE FlavourID = @flavourID";
                    OleDbCommand cmdJuiceStockExisting = new OleDbCommand(tblJuiceStockExisting, conn);
                    cmdJuiceStockExisting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flavourID", fID);
                    cmdJuiceStockExisting.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newquantity", updatedQty);
                    cmdJuiceStockExisting.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    matchFound = true;
                    break;
                }
                
            }

            if (!matchFound)
            {
                string tblJuiceStockNew = "INSERT INTO tblJuiceStock (FlavourID, Quantity, MinStockPOS) VALUES (@fID, @quantity, @minstock)";
                OleDbCommand cmdJuiceStockNew = new OleDbCommand(tblJuiceStockNew, conn);
                cmdJuiceStockNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fID", fID);
                cmdJuiceStockNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", qty);
                cmdJuiceStockNew.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minstock", amt);
                cmdJuiceStockNew.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note: this query works fine in Access when I replace parameters with the same values. Also, using breakpoints I identified that the parameters have the correct values set to them, the variables assigned to them are obtained within another method, all methods are called in the submit button event.

However, the Quantity value in TblJuiceStock remains the same.

[My tblJuiceStock table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkuIg.png)

Comment: I think the OleDbConnection requires `?` for the parameters in the Sql string and not named ones

Comment: I read into that, I use named parameters in several other oledbcommands within my application and it works fine. For example, if(!matchfound) contains an oledbcommand using named parameters and that query works fine.

Comment: My apologies for the statement. When I use OleDb against MsSql it complains. I admit I have never tried it against MsAccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time of messing about the answer was simple. 
OLEDB does work with named parameters but you have to declare them, if you don't declare them they use the parameters positioning to match them up.

My problem was that in my query string I had @newquantity first and @flavourID second, whereas when adding my parameters I added @flavourID first and @newquantity second.